# Error when trying to use a ternary operator in C#

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

Here's my code:

```
public void ToggleCheckBox()
{   
    if (chkSelected.Checked) ? chkSelected.Checked = false : chkSelected.Checked = true;

    //This works, but I want to write it using a ternary.
    if (chkSelected.Checked)
    {
        chkSelected.Checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        chkSelected.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

What did I mess up on? Thanks!

Comment: "Invalid expression '?'" - Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll update the question with the entire method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either do this:

```
if (chkSelected.Checked) chkSelected.Checked = false; else chkSelected.Checked = true;
```

...or this:

```
chkSelected.Checked = chkSelected.Checked ? false : true;
```

Or abandon the check and do this:

```
chkSelected.Checked = !chkSelected.Checked;
```

Comment: I'll take door number two! That looks like something I'd understand when reading further down the line. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Write this as

```
chkSelected.Checked = !chkSelected.Checked
```

instead.

To rewrite your exact example, it get's messy like this:

```
chkSelected.Checked =  (chkSelected.Checked) ? false : true;
```

The `?:` operator returns, in this case, either `true`or `false`. It cannot perform assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You're using assignment instead of comparison, and you don't need an `if` there. In fact, it isn't too clear what your *intent* is, but I'd guess it is:

```
chkSelected.Checked = !chkSelected.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to use like a assignation:

```
 chkSelected.Checked =(chkSelected.Checked ? false : true);
```

Ternary operator is used like a assignation

But here It is not really a good idea to do that here and do

```
chkSelected.Checked =!chkSelected.Checked;
```

Shorter way..

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
chkSelected.Checked = !chkSelected.Checked;
```

Also, it does not compile, because of the `if` you put in front of it. Remove that and it will work as well!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
chkSelected.Checked=(chkSelected.Checked ? false : true)
```

which can be shortened to:

```
chkSelected.Checked=!chkSelected.Checked
```